# `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format` when `curl -o`

Tags: curl

```
[root@localhost ~]# curl -o netatop-2.0.tar.gz --retry 3 http://www.atoptool.nl/download/netatop-2.0.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   324  100   324    0     0    606      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   606
[root@localhost ~]# tar -xvf netatop-2.0.tar.gz
tar: This does not look like a tar archive

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Then I tried to use chrome browser to download `http://www.atoptool.nl/download/netatop-2.0.tar.gz`,everything is ok.

What's the problem when I use `curl -o netatop-2.0.tar.gz --retry 3 http://www.atoptool.nl/download/netatop-2.0.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your test of the browser, how about using an option `-L`?

```
curl -L -o netatop-2.0.tar.gz --retry 3 http://www.atoptool.nl/download/netatop-2.0.tar.gz
```

#### Reference:

- [-L, --location](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L)

If this didn't work, I apologize.